# error when clicking renew for iOS certificates

Tags: ios, xcode

When I use the Organizer and click the "Renew" button, I get the following errors:

1. Ad Hoc: "There is no iOS Certificate with 'XP... on this team'"
2. App Store: "No value was provided for parameter 'deviceids'"

I am not sure why I receive these errors and would appreciate any help/guidance.

Comment: Same issue on my side. I am using XCode 4.5.

Comment: Same issue here.  Also using XCode 4.5.  I only have 7 days till expiration!!!  Help!!

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue and I couldn't even modify it online in developer portal. I solved it this way:

In organizer in provisioning profiles tab I clicked refresh in right lower corner. It generated some things for me (like developer profile). I still had to renew my profiles for apps and button still didn't work (but now the error was:"No value was provided for parameter 'certificateids'").

But it was possible now to click modify in Developer Portal were I could do it manually.

I hope it'll help someone.

Answer (score 7):

Use the developer portal to renew your certificates instead of xcode.
https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar error:

> No value was provided for the parameter 'appIdName'.

The solution was  similar. Download the provisioning profile via browser. Cheers.