# Why do I get the error "No value was provided for the parameter 'certificateIds'." when I hit renew in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I'm trying to renew a provisioning profile in Xcode, and upon hitting the renew button I am greeted with this error:

[image]

I'm aware that there are several SO posts* of people saying to simply login to the developer portal to renew profiles. However, if the button exists in Xcode, I would expect I should be able to use it.  Is this a bug in Xcode or am I missing a setting that allows this correctly work?

*[Distribution provisioning profile still expire even after clicking the renew button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361526/distribution-provisioning-profile-still-expire-even-after-clicking-the-renew-but) and
[error when clicking renew for iOS certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253618/error-when-clicking-renew-for-ios-certificates)

Comment: You get this error because Apple sucks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems like an Xcode bug. I would just go to the Developer Portal and renew the profiles there.

https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

Answer (score 0):

This works.  I have similar problem.  I have just to login to the dev center do create new profiles.  After that, goto Xcode organizer - devices - provisioning profiles and click "Refresh" at the bottom right of the screen.  This will automatically download the new profiles.  If you have problem, you may need to delete the expired profile manually from the provisioning portal and XCode.